# Issue with methods in Apache Flink TableEnvironment

Tags: java, interface, apache-flink

I tried to start using flink. But there is a problem when coding it

```java
EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings
  .newInstance()
  .inStreamingMode()
  //.inBatchMode()
  .build();

TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);

tEnv.executeSql(""); // This gets me error can't resolve executesql
TableResult result = tEnv.executeSql(""); // This will work
```

I thought first because This method has a return type so we should assign it. But if I use something the return type is void the problem remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your question really about, but if your SQL query contains nothing (`""`) don't be surprised having empty results or errors.

It should be something like:

```
tEnv.executeSql("SELECT * FROM yourTableName")
```

look this example -> [link](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-table/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/examples/java/basics/WordCountSQLExample.java)

read some [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/table/common/) it could help